# take the entire row from whith the smallest value from column 1

Tags: awk

I have this file

```
2  1
12 2
34 1
56 1
45 3
33 2
77 1
83 2
62 3
75 3
```

I want to take the entire row from whith the smallest value from column 1 like this

```
2  1
12 2
45 3
```

Comment: What did you try? As per you adding the `awk` tag, you must have tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to start with

```
{ if (!vals[$2] || vals[$2] > $1) vals[$2] = $1 }
END { for (idx in vals) print vals[idx] " " idx }
```

You should add robustness code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an  `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1 {a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i],i}' file
2 1
12 2
45 3
```

---

If I decode your data correctly:

```
cat file
0.020003 3
0.122203 3
0.122324 3
0.122445 3
0.122566 3
0.203582 43
0.225691 3
0.225812 3
0.226899 3
0.22702 3
0.228107 3
0.228228 3
0.229315 3
0.229436 3
0.325978 5
0.329179 3
0.3293 3
0.330387 3
0.330508 3
0.331595 3
0.331716 3
0.332803 3
0.332924 3
0.334011 3
0.334132 3
0.335219 3
0.33534 3
0.336427 3
0.336548 3
0.337635 3
0.337756 3
0.345776 43
0.345897 43
0.346018 43
0.346138 43
0.430173 5
0.430294 5
0.430414 5
0.430535 5
0.432667 3
0.432788 3
0.433875 3
0.433996 3
0.435083 3
0.435204 3
0.436291 3
0.436412 3
```

Then run the `awk` command:

```
awk '!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1 {a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i],i}' file
0.325978 5
0.203582 43
0.020003 3
```

And this is what you should expect. All result are the smallest using column `2` as an index

---

And since your data seems to be sorted, this works too:

```
awk '!a[$2]++' file
0.020003 3
0.203582 43
0.325978 5
```

Comment: When you give a response like this, you should write why. We are here to help, not magician.

Comment: i want the entire row with the smallest value in column one and the above answer diferent output

Comment: What is different, you are asking to get `2  1` `12 2` `45 3`, and this is what my `awk` answer gives you.

Comment: i apply this code as apart of tcl program for ns-2 simulator but it does not give me correct answer, thanks

Comment: Then your input data is not correct.  Or it may be bad formatting.  Give your real data and we can look at it.

Comment: this is part from input file

Comment: This solution works for the given data. So to help I need more data, and what do fail.

Comment: this part of input file 0.020003 3 
0.122203 3 
0.122324 3 
0.122445 3 
0.122566 3 
0.203582 43 
0.225691 3 
0.225812 3 
0.226899 3 
0.22702 3 
0.228107 3 
0.228228 3 
0.229315 3 
0.229436 3 
0.325978 5 
0.329179 3 
0.3293 3 
0.330387 3 
0.330508 3 
0.331595 3 
0.331716 3 
0.332803 3 
0.332924 3 
0.334011 3 
0.334132 3 
0.335219 3 
0.33534 3 
0.336427 3 
0.336548 3 
0.337635 3 
0.337756 3 
0.345776 43 
0.345897 43 
0.346018 43 
0.346138 43 
0.430173 5 
0.430294 5 
0.430414 5 
0.430535 5 
0.432667 3 
0.432788 3 
0.433875 3 
0.433996 3 
0.435083 3 
0.435204 3 
0.436291 3 
0.436412 3

Comment: and this the wrong output file 0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5

Comment: Update this in your post, using code tags to make it readable.

Comment: sorry but i apply your code as part of tcl program for ns2 like this set rt { { if (!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1) {a[$2]=$1;}  for (i in a) print (a[i],i) >> file1  }}}

Comment: 0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5

Comment: @user3400782 Sorry then, but can not help you any more than I have already done.  I do tell you to post date in you original post with code tags. You do not tell all you are doing, so this is not going anywhere.

Comment: I try it  (!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1) {a[$2]=$1;} for (i in a) print (a[i],i) >> file1   but it omit some rows of input file I think it has abug thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your file is sorted then you can just do:

```
awk '!a[$2]++' file
```

If it isn't then you can quickly sort it and feed the sorted data to `awk`:

```
sort -nk1 -nk2 file | awk '!a[$2]++'
```

**or**

```
awk '!a[$2]++' < <(sort -nk1 -nk2 file)
```