# i need the least value for column 1 for every column 2 value

Tags: awk, tcl

input file

```
0.020003 3 
0.122203 3 
0.122324 3 
0.122445 3 
0.122566 3 
0.203582 43 
0.225691 3 
0.225812 3 
0.226899 3 
0.22702 3 
0.228107 3 
0.228228 3 
0.229315 3 
0.229436 3 
0.325978 5 
0.329179 3 
0.3293 3 
0.330387 3 
0.330508 3 
0.331595 3 
0.331716 3 
0.332803 3 
0.332924 3 
0.334011 3 
0.334132 3 
0.335219 3 
0.33534 3 
0.336427 3 
0.336548 3 
0.337635 3 
0.337756 3 
0.345776 43 
0.345897 43 
0.346018 43 
0.346138 43 
0.430173 5 
0.430294 5 
0.430414 5 
0.430535 5 
0.432667 3 
0.432788 3 
0.433875 3 
0.433996 3 
0.435083 3 
0.435204 3 
0.436291 3 
0.436412 3 
0.437499 3 
0.43762 3 
0.438707 3 
0.438828 3 
0.439915 3 
0.440036 3 
0.441123 3 
0.441244 3 
0.442331 3 
0.442452 3 
0.443539 3 
0.44366 3 
0.444747 3 
0.444868 3 
0.445955 3 
0.446076 3 
0.447163 3 
0.447284 3 
0.448371 3 
0.448492 3 
0.449579 3 
0.4497 3 
0.450787 3 
0.450908 3 
0.491995 43 
0.492116 43 
0.493203 43 
0.493324 43 
0.494411 43 
0.494532 43 
0.495619 43 
0.49574 43 
0.509831 103 
0.535661 5 
0.535782 5 
0.536869 5 
0.53699 5 
0.538077 5 
0.538198 5 
0.538493 3 
0.538614 3 
0.539285 5 
0.539406 5 
0.539701 3 
0.539822 3 
0.540909 3 
0.54103 3 
0.542117 3 
0.542238 3 
0.543325 3 
0.543446 3 
0.544533 3 
0.544654 3 
0.545741 3 
0.545862 3 
0.546949 3 
0.54707 3 
0.548157 3 
0.548278 3 
0.549365 3 
0.549486 3 
0.550573 3 
0.550694 3 
0.551781 3 
0.551902 3 
0.552989 3 
0.55311 3 
0.554197 3 
0.554318 3 
0.555405 3 
0.555526 3 
0.556613 3 
0.556734 3 
0.557821 3 
0.557942 3 
0.559029 3 
0.55915 3 
0.560237 3 
0.560358 3 
0.561445 3 
0.561566 3 
0.562653 3 
0.562774 3 
0.563861 3 
0.563982 3 
0.565069 3 
0.56519 3 
0.566277 3 
0.566398 3 
0.567485 3 
0.567606 3 
0.568693 3 
0.568814 3 
0.569901 3 
0.570022 3 
0.571109 3 
0.57123 3 
0.572317 3 
0.572438 3 
0.573525 3 
0.573646 3 
0.574733 3 
0.574854 3 
0.575941 3 
0.576062 3 
0.635483 43 
0.635604 43 
0.636691 43 
0.636812 43 
0.637899 43 
0.63802 43 
0.639107 43 
0.639228 43 
0.640315 43 
0.640436 43 
0.641149 5 
0.64127 5 
0.641523 43 
0.641644 43 
0.642357 5 
0.642478 5 
0.642731 43 
0.642852 43 
0.643565 5 
0.643686 5 
0.643939 43 
0.64406 43 
0.644773 5 
0.644894 5 
0.645981 5 
0.646102 5 
0.646397 3 
0.646518 3 
0.647189 5 
0.64731 5 
0.647605 3 
0.647726 3 
0.650813 5 
0.650934 5 
0.651229 3 
0.65135 3 
0.652021 5 
0.652142 5 
0.652437 3 
0.652558 3 
0.653645 3 
0.653766 3 
0.654853 3 
0.654974 3 
0.656061 3 
0.656182 3 
0.657269 3 
0.65739 3 
0.658477 3 
0.658598 3 
0.659685 3 
0.659806 3 
0.660893 3 
0.661014 3 
0.662101 3 
0.662222 3 
0.663309 3 
0.66343 3 
0.664517 3 
0.664638 3 
0.665725 3 
0.665846 3 
0.666933 3 
0.667054 3 
0.668141 3 
0.668262 3 
0.669349 3 
0.66947 3 
0.670557 3 
0.670678 3 
0.671765 3 
0.671886 3 
0.672973 3 
0.673094 3 
0.674181 3 
0.674302 3 
0.675389 3 
0.67551 3 
0.676597 3 
0.676718 3 
0.677805 3 
0.677926 3 
0.679013 3 
0.679134 3 
0.680221 3 
0.680342 3 
0.681429 3 
0.68155 3 
0.682637 3 
0.682758 3 
0.683845 3 
0.683966 3 
0.685053 3 
0.685174 3 
0.686261 3 
0.686382 3 
0.687469 3 
0.68759 3 
0.688677 3 
0.688798 3 
0.689885 3 
0.690006 3 
0.691093 3 
0.691214 3 
0.692301 3 
0.692422 3 
0.693509 3 
0.69363 3 
0.694717 3 
0.694838 3 
0.695925 3 
0.696046 3 
0.697133 3 
0.697254 3 
0.698341 3 
0.698462 3 
0.699549 3 
0.69967 3 
0.700757 3 
0.700878 3 
0.701965 3 
0.702086 3 
0.703173 3 
0.703294 3 
0.704381 3 
0.704502 3 
0.705589 3 
0.70571 3 
0.706797 3 
0.706918 3 
0.708005 3 
0.708126 3 
0.709213 3 
0.709334 3 
0.710421 3 
0.710542 3 
0.711629 3 
0.71175 3 
0.712025 103 
0.712146 103 
0.712267 103 
0.712388 103 
0.712837 3 
0.712958 3 
0.714045 3 
0.714166 3 
0.715253 3 
0.715374 3 
0.716461 3 
0.716582 3 
0.717669 3 
0.71779 3
```

output file

```
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.020003 3
```

what i need otput file

```
0.020003 3 
0.325978 5 
0.203582 43 
0.509831 103
```

every row is repeated in the original file and in the wrong output file

Answer (score 0):

My answer is still valid from this question: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298715)

```
awk '!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1 {a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i],i}' file
0.325978 5
0.509831 103
0.203582 43
0.020003 3
```

And this works:

```
awk '!a[$2]++' file
0.020003 3
0.203582 43
0.325978 5
0.509831 103
```

Comment: i apply your code as part of tcl program for ns2 like this set rt { { if (!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1) {a[$2]=$1;} for (i in a) print (a[i],i) >> file1 }}}   how can i apply this awk '!a[$2]||a[$2]>$1 {a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i],i}' file   as part of my tcl program

Comment: Then you should ask that question in a post.  Why not use `awk` directly.

Comment: because ns-2 siulator use tcl and i already use some awk function in it

Comment: You should tag your question appropriately. This is a working awk answer.

Comment: @jaypal Except that it's _actually_ a “working awk invoked from the Unix shell answer”. Just sayin'…

Comment: Oopsie daisy! @DonalFellows